# How to access newly created DOM elements in JS? (I have used appendChild)

Tags: dom, addeventlistener, appendchild

I am making a to do list. Each list item includes a remove button when created.

But I cannot access these remove buttons in my script, because it is not included in my DOM, although I used '.appendChild'. Can anyone help?

```js
const buttonSubmit = document.querySelector('#button-submit');
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const icons = document.querySelector('#icons');
let toDoList = document.querySelector('#todolist');
const input = document.querySelector('#formtext');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const newListItem = document.createElement('li');

  newListItem.innerHTML = '<span>' + input.value + '</span>' +
    '<span id="icons">' +
    '<button id="check" class="buttonlist">' + '<img src="checked.png" alt="">' + '</button>' +
    '<button id="remove" class="buttonlist">' + '<img src="remove.png" alt="">' + '</button>' +
    '<button id="edit" class="buttonlist">' + '<img src="edit.png" alt="">' + '</button>' + '</span>';

  toDoList.appendChild(newListItem);
  form.reset();
})

const buttonCheck = document.querySelector('#check');
const buttonEdit = document.querySelector('#edit');
const buttonRemove = document.getElementById('remove');

buttonRemove.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('remove list item');
})
```

```html
<div class="container-box">
  <h1>To Do List</h1>
  <br>

  <form action="">

    <input type="text" id="formtext" name="formtext">

    <button id="button-submit">Add Item</button>

  </form>
  <br><br><br><br>

  <!-- Dynamic list here -->
  <ul id="todolist"> </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problems

ids must be unique, every time you add a task to the list -- after the first one everything is invalid HTML. When directed to an id the browser will find the first id then stop and ignore the duplicate ids. Use class and/or name attributes for any replicated tags.

The reason why the remove button doesn't work is because the reference to the button was defined when it didn't exist.

**Figure I**

```
// After page is loaded...
const buttonRemove = document.getElementById('remove');
// Console will tell you buttonRemove is null
// User has not entered any data nor has user clicked the add button
```

Moreover, even if that was fixed by referencing the button ***after*** it was created, binding it as shown on **Figure II** will only work for the first button only.

**Figure II**

```
buttonRemove.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('remove list item'); // Don't use alert() use console.log()
})
```

### Solution

Reference tags ***after*** they are created. In the OP (**O**riginal **P**ost), the contents of the `<li>` is rendered htmlString which makes referencing newly created tags problematic plus binding to dynamically created tags individually should be avoided if it's feasible and practical in which in most cases it is.

To handle events for an unknown amount of dynamically created tags, bind the event to a static ancestor tag, which in the OP is `<ul>` or any of it's parent tags (even `<body>`, `document`, and `window` but it's best to be as close as possible). Then make it so the event handler controls which tags respond and how. See **Appendix** located at the very end of this answer for more details.

There are two examples:

**Example A** - revised OP code

**Example B** - a todo list using **HTMLFormElement** interface, see **Appendix**

**Both examples have commented step-by-step details**

### Example A

```js
// Reference <form>, <ul>, and <input>
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const list = document.querySelector('ul');
const input = document.querySelector('#text');

// Bind <form> to submit event
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  // Stop default behavior of <form> during submit ecent
  e.preventDefault();
  // Create <li> and <output>
  const item = document.createElement('li');
  const out = document.createElement('output');
  // Assign value of <input> to the value of <output>
  out.value = input.value;
  // Add <output> to <li> -- <li> to <ul>
  item.append(out);
  list.append(item);
  /*
  Run a for loop 3 times -- on each iteration...
  ...create an <input> and assign type as "button"...
  ...buttons [name] and [value] is determined by current index...
  ...add button to <li>
  */
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let btn = document.createElement('input');
    btn.type = 'button';
    let cmd = i === 0 ? 'done' : i === 1 ? 'edit' : i === 2 ? 'remove' : false;
    btn.name = cmd;
    btn.value = cmd;
    item.append(btn);
  }
  // Reset <form>
  form.reset();
});

// Bind <ul> to click event
list.addEventListener('click', manageList);

// Event handler always passes event object by default
function manageList(e) {
  // Reference the tag user clicked
  const clk = e.target;
  // If user clicked a remove button remove it's parent tag
  if (clk.name === 'remove') {
    clk.parentElement.remove();
  }

  if (clk.name === 'edit') {
    console.log('EDIT');
  }

  if (clk.name === 'done') {
    console.log('DONE');
  }
}
```

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

[type='button'] {
  text-transform: capitalize
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="text" name="text" type="text">
  <button>Add Item</button>
</form>
<br>
<ul></ul>
```

### Example B

```js
// Bind <form> to click event
document.forms.todo.onclick = taskList;
// Event handler akways passes the event object
function taskList(e) {
  // Reference the tag user clicked
  const clk = e.target;
  // Reference all form controls
  const IO = this.elements;
  /*
  If the user clicked the add button...
  ...reference the <ul>...
  ...create <li> and <output>...
  ...add text from <input> to <output>...
  ...add <output> to <li>...
  ...Run a for loop 3 times -- on each iteration...
  ...create an <button> and assign type as "button"...
  ...buttons [name] and text is determined by current index...
  ...add button to <li>...
  ...add <li> to <ul>...
  ...clear <input>
  */
  if (clk.name == 'add') {
    const list = IO.list.firstElementChild;
    const item = document.createElement('li');
    const text = document.createElement('output');
    text.value = IO.data.value;
    item.append(text);
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      let btn = document.createElement('button');
      btn.type = 'button';
      let cmd = i === 0 ? 'done' : i === 1 ? 'edit' : i === 2 ? 'remove' : false;
      btn.name = cmd;
      btn.textContent = cmd;
      item.append(btn);
    }
    list.append(item);
    IO.data.value = '';
  }
  /*
  If the user clicked a remove button...
  ...find the <li> ancestor of remove button and remove 
  it thereby removing the <output> and itself as well
  */
  if (clk.name === 'remove') {
    clk.closest('li').remove();
  }
  if (clk.name === 'done') {
    console.log('DONE');
  }
  if (clk.name === 'edit') {
    console.log('EDIT');
  }
}
```

```html
<form id='todo'>
  <input id='data' required><button name='add' type='button'>Add</button>
  <fieldset id='list'>
    <ul></ul>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

### Appendix

[Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

[Event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation)

[HTMLFormElement](https://javascript.info/form-elements)

[HTMLFormControlsCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)

[Form Controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#form-associated_content)